# how to call a stored function from jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am creating a login page using custom tag, in the below code i want to execute a stored oracle function where that function will take 2 parameter (name,password) to authenticate and return a number.  But when i compile the below code it gives an error saying ( found: int) incompatible type.  please tell me where am i going wrong ? am i calling the function correctly ?

```
package pack.java;
import pack.java.MyModel;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MyController extends TagSupport
{
    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    public int doStartTag()throws JspException
    {
        request = (HttpServletRequest)pageContext.getRequest();              
        response = (HttpServletResponse)pageContext.getResponse();
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }   

    public void check()
    {
        HttpSession mysession = request.getSession();
        Connection con;
        CallableStatement stmt;
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
        try {         
            String aa = (String)MyModel.name.trim();
            String bb = (String)MyModel.pass.trim();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","gaurav","oracle");
            stmt = con.prepareCall("select usercheck1(?,?) from dual");
            stmt.setString(1, aa);
            stmt.setString(2, bb);       
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String empid = rs.getString (1);
                    mysession.setAttribute("user", empid);
                    if (empid != null) {
                        response.sendRedirect("/Myjsp/selectaction.jsp");
                    }
                    else
                        out.println("InValid User");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {}
    }

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        check();
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

below is the stored function

```
create or replace function usercheck1
    (uname varchar2, upass varchar2)
    return number
as 
    numb number;
begin
    select (employe_id)
      into numb
      from record
     where name = uname
       and password = upass;
    return numb;
end usercheck1;
/
```

executing the function using the below statement

```
select usercheck1 ('ghg','aa') from dual;
```

Comment: On which line the error is reported ?

Comment: It says incompatible type
found:int,
required: java.sql.ResultSet,
on line rs=stmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: Some time in the near future, please go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get your formatting reviewed.

Answer (score 13):

To execute a function, the canonical way is to use a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). This is a special case (*subclass*) of `PreparedStatement`.

In addition, you have to specify the *right* output parameters type using one of the [`registerOutParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29) methods. Once the call is completed ([`execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29)), you extract the output value from the statement itself. Not through a `ResultSet`.

All of this lead to something like:

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call usercheck1(?, ?)}");
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Prepare a `call`

stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
# Setup out parameter type    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stmt.setString(2,aa);       
stmt.setString(3,bb);
stmt.execute(); 
#    ^^^^^^^
# execute the statement

int output = stmt.getInt(1);
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^
# Extract the result from the statement itself
```

---

A totally different way of doing, is to actually use a `SELECT` query to call the function. This is what was suggested by the OP in the question. That way, you can use a `ResultSet` as usual to extract the values:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT usercheck1(?, ?) FROM DUAL");
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Prepare a statement

stmt.setString(2,aa);       
stmt.setString(3,bb);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); 
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
# execute the query

while(rs.next()) {
  int output = rs.getInt(1);
  #            ^^^^^^^^^
  # Extract the result from the `ResultSet`

  # ...
  # do whatever you want with the data

}
```

Comment: This can't be right... Aren't CallableStatement only for procedures and not for functions? Otherwise, how would you get the function return value at the 0th argument position?

Comment: Actually, see: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/calling-PL-SQL-from-Java.html#GUID-F2FC29B6-F20F-49FB-99CB-56C9C15ECFB5

Comment: Why do you need curly braces?

Comment: When using `FROM DUAL` you can't execute procedure with data editing (only select).

Answer (score 4):

First off you say the proc returns a number but your code is expecting a resultset which returns a string?
Anyway, assuming that your proc returns an int. 
Change these lines

```
    stmt=con.prepareCall("call usercheck1(?,?)");

    stmt.setString(1,aa);
stmt.setString(2,bb);       
    rs=stmt.executeUpdate();
```

to

```
    stmt=con.prepareCall ("{? = call usercheck1(?, ?)}");

    stmt.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
    stmt.setString(2,aa);       
     stmt.setString(3,bb);
    stmt.execute(); 
    int output =stmt.getInt (1);
```

If you are actually expecting a string as a result from the proc, then change 
to

```
    stmt=con.prepareCall ("{? = call usercheck1(?, ?)}");

    stmt.registerOutParameter (1, Types.VARCHAR2);
    stmt.setString(2,aa);       
     stmt.setString(3,bb);
    stmt.execute(); 
    String output =stmt.getString (1);
```

ResultSets are used for cursors, and would require you to specify your out parameters as such. 
Hope that helps.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/samapp2.htm

If you are using a newer version of oracle >= 9i, you may want to use the begin end syntax.

Comment: thanks for your input, however when i tried executing the code by making changes you suggested the code doesnt work, the login fails because i think the function is not getting executed.  I am updating the function i have created, please check what might be going wrong

Comment: I cant tell you what is going wrong unless you tell me what is happening and what you are doing now. maybe you should repost your new code...

Comment: Also, try changing your callable sql code to "begin ? := usercheck1(?,?); end;"  This is the new oracle 9i syntax.

Comment: i have re-posted the code, when i try to login the page doesnt redirect. I have used both the statements ( begin ? := usercheck1(?,?); end; and {? = call usercheck1(?, ?)} ) and none of it works... I am using oracle 10g

Answer (score 1):

Others suggests running the query through a select statement, but this will throw an exception if the function does any DML. Using a CallableStatement  is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more contemporary solution using JPA (`javax.persistence.EntityManager`):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

. . .

final int myResult;
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(connection -> {
    try (CallableStatement function = 
            connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call usercheck1(?, ?) }")) {
        function.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        function.setString(2, aa);
        function.setString(3, bb);
        function.execute();
        myResult = function.getInt(1);
    }
} );
```

These are the main dependencies to indicate what lib versions the solution works with:

```
compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.7.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
```

As an alternative to `doWork()` and assigning the stored function result with `getXxx(1)`, you can use [`doReturningWork()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doReturningWork-org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork-).

### In Kotlin

Here's the solution in Kotlin (and using `doReturningWork`):

```
@PersistenceContext
lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

. . .

val session : Session = entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java)
var myResult = session.doReturningWork { connection: Connection ->
    connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call usercheck1(?, ?) }").use { function ->
        function.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER)
        function.setString(2, aa)
        function.setString(3, bb)
        function.execute()
        return@doReturningWork function.getInt(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`executeUpdate()` returns `int`, See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) for more details. I believe you are expecting a `ResultSet`,

Change below line,

```
 rs=stmt.executeUpdate();
```

to

`rs=stmt.executeQuery();`

See [executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) for more info.

Comment: Thanks it worked.. though i hd to use query stmt=con.prepareCall("select usercheck1(?,?) from dual");

Comment: The call of executeUpdate should be in transaction